# Is conditional entropy a convex function?

Tags: optimization, convex-analysis, convex-optimization, entropy

A conditional entropy can be expressed in the following way,
$H_{V_t}(V_s) = -\sum_{s,t}p(s,t)\log{p_t(s)} = -\sum_{s,t}p(s,t)\log{\frac{p(s,t)}{\sum_{s'}{p(s',t)}}}$

$s$ and $t$ are defined on finite domain, say $s,t\in{\{00,01,11,10\}}$. Each value of $p(s,t)$ is an independent variable. Is conditional entropy a convex function under this circumstances?

Comment: As it stands, I can see three disconcerting things:
1) I think there is a minus missing in the formula of conditional entropy.
2) If $p_s(t)$ stands for the conditional probability, then the denominator in the last expression should be summed over the other variable (here $t$)
3) A function is convex *in* some variable. The variable is not clear here.

Comment: variable is $p(s,t)$, not $s$ and $t$. The question is also improved accordingly.